# Asp.net Dropdownlist : Want to hide the initial value when page loaded for second time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a dropdown list and then added items to it with an initial value of -1 with text "select country"

My question is: when I select something from the list and later on change my mind to one item to another item. Now I wanted to hide the initial value "select country" from the list on postback

Comment: Show some code and describe your question in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check inside **postback** that if dropdownlist value has been selected than disable the "Select Country" option

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
if(ddlCountry.SelectedIndex>0)
   ddlCountry.Items.FindByValue("-1").Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this in page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack)
     {
       if(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex>0)
            DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue("-1").Enabled = false;
     }
}
```